# Atleast one and atleast not one

Tags: sql, oracle

**Requirement:**

For a policy: At least one item (RAP03.propid) had discount (rap14.covid = 'SS') AND At least one item did not have discount (SS). Suppose we have one policy (rap01.plcy) , and with this policy we have 2 items (rap03.propid). So with one item SS should be there and with one item SS should not be there. I tried below but I got zero records. Is there any way to check both condition together.

we have to look respect of policy and item (PROPID) as well. One propid must contain SS but other propid must not contain SS.

**Required result:**

```
PLCY, PROPID, COVID
000000967428613 010 SS
000000967428613 011 BB
```

```
AND EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
    /*+ use_hash(RAP03 rap14) */
  FROM rap03
JOIN rap14
ON  rap14.j31_pt_line_cat_cd = rap01.j01_PT_LINE_CAT_CD 
AND rap14.j31_pt_cdb_part_id = rap01.j01_PT_CDB_PART_ID
AND rap14.j31_pt_state_cd    = rap01.j01_PT_STATE_CD
AND rap14.plcy               = RAP01.plcy
AND rap14.propid             = RAP03.propid
AND trim(rap14.covid)        = 'SS'
AND tt.JA2_EFFDT_T BETWEEN rap14.enddt_t AND (rap14.dropdt_t - 1)
--
  WHERE RAP03.J12_PT_LINE_CAT_CD = RAP01.J01_PT_LINE_CAT_CD
  AND RAP03.J12_PT_CDB_PART_ID   = RAP01.J01_PT_CDB_PART_ID
  AND RAP03.J12_PT_STATE_CD      = RAP01.J01_PT_STATE_CD
  AND RAP03.PLCY                 = RAP01.PLCY
  AND tt.JA2_EFFDT_T BETWEEN rap03.adddt_t AND (rap03.dropdt_t  - 1)
  ) 
--
AND NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
    /*+ use_hash(RAP03 rap14) */
  FROM rap03
JOIN rap14
ON  rap14.j31_pt_line_cat_cd = rap01.j01_PT_LINE_CAT_CD 
AND rap14.j31_pt_cdb_part_id = rap01.j01_PT_CDB_PART_ID
AND rap14.j31_pt_state_cd    = rap01.j01_PT_STATE_CD
AND rap14.plcy               = RAP01.plcy
AND rap14.propid             = RAP03.propid
AND trim(rap14.covid)        = 'SS'
AND tt.JA2_EFFDT_T BETWEEN rap14.enddt_t AND (rap14.dropdt_t - 1)
--
  WHERE RAP03.J12_PT_LINE_CAT_CD = RAP01.J01_PT_LINE_CAT_CD
  AND RAP03.J12_PT_CDB_PART_ID   = RAP01.J01_PT_CDB_PART_ID
  AND RAP03.J12_PT_STATE_CD      = RAP01.J01_PT_STATE_CD
  AND RAP03.PLCY                 = RAP01.PLCY
  AND tt.JA2_EFFDT_T BETWEEN rap03.adddt_t AND (rap03.dropdt_t  - 1)
  )
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to give a [MRE] including: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data; a complete (and minimal) example of the query you are using that we can run; an English (not code) explanation of the problem; the issues/errors with your code; and your expected output for that sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You currently have `WHERE EXISTS(query) AND NOT EXISTS(query)` and both queries are identical; which is always going to be false.

I ***think*** the logic you want is `WHERE (at least one record exists with 'SS') AND (at least one record exists that's not 'SS')`

```
AND EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
    /*+ use_hash(RAP03 rap14) */
  FROM rap03
JOIN rap14
ON  rap14.j31_pt_line_cat_cd = rap01.j01_PT_LINE_CAT_CD 
AND rap14.j31_pt_cdb_part_id = rap01.j01_PT_CDB_PART_ID
AND rap14.j31_pt_state_cd    = rap01.j01_PT_STATE_CD
AND rap14.plcy               = RAP01.plcy
AND rap14.propid             = RAP03.propid
AND trim(rap14.covid)        = 'SS'
AND tt.JA2_EFFDT_T BETWEEN rap14.enddt_t AND (rap14.dropdt_t - 1)
--
  WHERE RAP03.J12_PT_LINE_CAT_CD = RAP01.J01_PT_LINE_CAT_CD
  AND RAP03.J12_PT_CDB_PART_ID   = RAP01.J01_PT_CDB_PART_ID
  AND RAP03.J12_PT_STATE_CD      = RAP01.J01_PT_STATE_CD
  AND RAP03.PLCY                 = RAP01.PLCY
  AND tt.JA2_EFFDT_T BETWEEN rap03.adddt_t AND (rap03.dropdt_t  - 1)
  ) 
--

AND EXISTS -- CHANGE HERE (NOT removed)

  (SELECT 1
    /*+ use_hash(RAP03 rap14) */
  FROM rap03
JOIN rap14
ON  rap14.j31_pt_line_cat_cd = rap01.j01_PT_LINE_CAT_CD 
AND rap14.j31_pt_cdb_part_id = rap01.j01_PT_CDB_PART_ID
AND rap14.j31_pt_state_cd    = rap01.j01_PT_STATE_CD
AND rap14.plcy               = RAP01.plcy
AND rap14.propid             = RAP03.propid

AND trim(rap14.covid)       <> 'SS'  -- CHANGE HERE (= becomes <>)

AND tt.JA2_EFFDT_T BETWEEN rap14.enddt_t AND (rap14.dropdt_t - 1)
--
  WHERE RAP03.J12_PT_LINE_CAT_CD = RAP01.J01_PT_LINE_CAT_CD
  AND RAP03.J12_PT_CDB_PART_ID   = RAP01.J01_PT_CDB_PART_ID
  AND RAP03.J12_PT_STATE_CD      = RAP01.J01_PT_STATE_CD
  AND RAP03.PLCY                 = RAP01.PLCY
  AND tt.JA2_EFFDT_T BETWEEN rap03.adddt_t AND (rap03.dropdt_t  - 1)
  )
```

Combining them reduces code, but may in-fact be slower because it can't 'stop' at the first record found...

```
AND EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1
    /*+ use_hash(RAP03 rap14) */
  FROM rap03
  JOIN rap14
    ON  rap14.j31_pt_line_cat_cd = rap01.j01_PT_LINE_CAT_CD 
    AND rap14.j31_pt_cdb_part_id = rap01.j01_PT_CDB_PART_ID
    AND rap14.j31_pt_state_cd    = rap01.j01_PT_STATE_CD
    AND rap14.plcy               = RAP01.plcy
    AND rap14.propid             = RAP03.propid
    AND tt.JA2_EFFDT_T BETWEEN rap14.enddt_t AND (rap14.dropdt_t - 1)
--
  WHERE RAP03.J12_PT_LINE_CAT_CD = RAP01.J01_PT_LINE_CAT_CD
    AND RAP03.J12_PT_CDB_PART_ID   = RAP01.J01_PT_CDB_PART_ID
    AND RAP03.J12_PT_STATE_CD      = RAP01.J01_PT_STATE_CD
    AND RAP03.PLCY                 = RAP01.PLCY
    AND tt.JA2_EFFDT_T BETWEEN rap03.adddt_t AND (rap03.dropdt_t  - 1)
  HAVING
    MAX(CASE WHEN TRIM(rap14.covid) = 'SS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
    AND
    MIN(CASE WHEN TRIM(rap14.covid) = 'SS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
)
```

There may be better ways to formulate the query, but we would need more context (table definitions, full query, full logic explained, etc).

Comment: WHERE (at least one record exists with 'SS') AND (at least one record exists that's not 'SS') , this is somehow correct. But with more twist. Suppose we have one policy (rap01.plcy) , and with this policy we have 2 items (rap03.propid). So with one item SS should be there and with one item SS should not be there.

Comment: @KaushalTalniya - You now appear to be asking a different question.  Please start a new question, but include example data to demonstrate the scenario and the logic you require.  Some useful advice on how to write such a question can be found here:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query  and  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: edited the question with desired results.

Comment: @kaushaltalniya You need to include source data as well as expected results. You will benefit from simplifying the problem down to a simpler example that you can learn from. (Please read the two links I provided for you, about Minimal and Reproducible examples.) You should open new questions rather than materially change existing questions.